# Integrate A/B test into Magnolia

Tags: java, magnolia, ab-testing

We would like to use Magnolia in our project, however the business would like to have A/B testing integrated into Magnolia, I'm new using this CMS so I don't have an idea how can this be accomplish.

Do you guys know if there is a good A/B testing tool that can be integrated with Magnolia? Or does anyone have an idea on how to do it?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you describe an experiement you would like to be able to instrument?

Answer (score 0):

Magnolia provides A/B testing functionality out of the box. First you have to create `variants` of the page that you want to test. Let's take as an example an ecommerce product details page. One with red button "Buy now" and another with blue button "Purchase now". Next thing is split the users in two groups or as they're also called `traits` for this you need something that will gather specific information for the users, e.g. you can split them by geo-location or other demographic criteria like language or if you want to split them in percentages like 50-50 you will need to write your own service/module that creates two buckets and assigns people to each of them while tracking the amount of people remains consistent to the preconfigured percentages.

You can read about traits here: https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Creating+custom+traits

Variants here: https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Personalization#Personalization-Variantsarealternativecontent

and here is an example of personalisation campaign and how it works: https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/My+first+personalized+campaign

Answer (score 0):

For A/B testing you need a control page (A), a variation of the page (B) and a goal which has to be met for deciding which is the winner.
The set up of the page variations (A/B) can be done through Magnolia's personalisation where each variation of the test will be represented by a variant in Magnolia. You can find the links about Personalisation in previous answer (I can't post more than two links yet).

One possible solution is to use Google Analytics Experiments for the management of the duration of the test, the number of visitors redirected to each variant and even the goal that has to be met in order to get a winner of the test. The advantage of using a tool like Google Analytics is that you can take advantage of the analytics already provided for you like event counting, page visits or session durations. Also the redirecting to each variant of the test will be done by Google Analytics, so you don't need to use traits just create the variants in Magnolia without any particular audience (or trait).
You can find more info about Google Analytics Experiments here:

https://support.google.com/analytics/topic/1745146?hl=en&ref_topic=1120718

The idea is that you implement a module with a content app for the experiments created on Google Analytics based on variants of a page created in Magnolia using the Google Analytics Experiments API.

Tests are called experiments in Google Analytics. The setup of the goal, duration of the test and how visitors will be redirected is managed by Google Analytics. You only need to embed a Javascript snippet (provided by the API when creating the experiment) in the "control" page in Magnolia. You can embed JS snippets in any page with the Marketing Tags module:

https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Marketing+Tags+app